# How to use view content as node content

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm trying to show a view on homepage node. I created a view that filters 5 first news, and it works perfectly, but I want it to be shown on homepage only.

Any idea?

Comment: Is it a page view or a block view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a block view, all you have to do is add the block to a region that is available on the home page template.  Edit the block, scroll to the bottom choose the option that says `Show only on the selected pages`, then type `<front>` in the text area.  This will force the block to only show on the home page.

Comment: Sorry of being late to read this. Both of you are correct. I needed both a page and a block to display where I wanted, but as I'm a bit newbie I didn't understand it, but now I'm ok.

You have both positive vote, but I need to put one of you as the correct one.. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 2):

If your view is a page View (and not a block view), then your home page can be set from `Configuration > Site Information` (under `System` section) which is at `admin/config/system/site-information` of your site.

Set the *Default front page* path to your View's path.